# How to remove whitespace in array element?

Tags: php, arrays

HI I got so many empty & white-space element in array. anyone know how to remove it? IN PHP

```
$my[0] = ""
$my[1] = 5.21
$my[2] = 425
$my[3] = " "
$my[4] = " "
$my[5] = 75
```

I have used array_filter to remove empty but still white-space How to remove that please any one told me ?

```
array_filter($my);  //Remove only empty array element
//My output is now
$my[1] = 5.21
$my[2] = 425
$my[3] = " "
$my[4] = " "
$my[5] = 75

//But i want only
$my[1] = 5.21
$my[2] = 425
$my[5] = 75
```

Please Help me to remove white-space.Thank you.

Comment: Tried something?Can do with looping ;-)

Comment: No, How ? Please leave here comment

Comment: you have to use a custom function.

Comment: user array_filter and use the function provided by @Gautam3164 without loop :)

Comment: See my second answer.It will probable for you

Comment: have a look with my answer.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 till not working your code.

Comment: @GunjanPatel Have you tried with my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401139/how-to-remove-whitespace-in-array-element#answer-26401178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just used below code :

```
$my[0] = ""
$my[1] = 5.21
$my[2] = 425
$my[3] = " "
$my[4] = " "
$my[5] = 75

print_r(array_filter(array_map("trim",$my)));
```

Comment: trim will not work if you have `array(0=>'""', 1=>'" "', 25)`

Comment: @jogesh_pi: i have try to following the question that post by him.

Comment: @GunjanPatel: Then what is your expected output?

Comment: @hardiksolanki Yes got it But it's my problem because in array it's not come white spaces but Unicode of white spaces so it's not work for me i think

Answer (score 1):

According to you Expect Result this is what you can done with:

```
$arr = array_filter(array_map('floatval', $arr));
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://codepad.org/kKg2sfiq)</kbd>

Comment: @GunjanPatel Seems you didn't share the actually what you have and what you want.

Comment: I want just remove white spaces from array .

Answer (score 1):

Just use trim fucntion :

```
trim($my);
```

instead of

```
array_filter($my);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$my = array_map("trim", $my);
```

This calls the function trim() on all elements in the array and returns a new array of the modified variables.

Answer (score 0):

Can do with looping like

```
foreach($myarray as $array) {

    if(trim($array) != "") {
         $newarray[] = $array;
    }
}
print_r($newarray);
```

But it will create an array with new keys.To keep existing `keys-values` you can also do like

```
foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {

    if(trim($value) != "") {
         $newarray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: It Works but till remove empty not remove array element that have only white-space .

Comment: means.you want to keep white spaces?

Comment: No, I want to remove it

Comment: Yes got it But it's my problem because in array it's not come white spaces  but Unicode of white spaces so it's not work for me i think